# Powershell - Check if one or both Services are running

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to check for running Services on different Windows Servers.
there can be two services running (old or new version or both, with slightly different names)

need the output like: "new version" , "old version" or "both versions"

I wanted to simply check with the `Get-Process` command but I can't really get to a conclusion how to get my output and how to check if both are running.

Started like the following:  how can I finish my script?  or am I completely wrong? couldn't find anything that helps.

```
if (Get-Service "NAME" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"})
{Write-Host "New Client running"

}
if (Get-Service "NAME_old" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"})
{Write-Host "old Client running"

}
Else {Write-Host ”No Client found”}
```

obviously this script doesn't quite work. tested on a Server where only the new client is running and it outputs:

```
New Client running
No Client found
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `if` statement to `elseif` - this way the `else` block only runs if neither of the two preceding conditions hold true:

```
if (Get-Service "NAME" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"})
{
  Write-Host "New Client running"
}
elseif (Get-Service "NAME_old" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"})
{
  Write-Host "old Client running"
}
else {
  Write-Host "No Client found"
}
```

Comment: when i change it to elseif' it skips the check for the old client if the new one (first if sequence) is running...   so i can not find out if both are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your three `if` statements if you track your `Get-Service` results:

```
if ($newclient = Get-Service "NAME" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where Status -eq Running) {
    Write-Host 'New Client running'
}
if ($oldclient = Get-Service "NAME_old" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where Status -eq Running) {
    Write-Host 'old Client running'
}
if (-not ($newclient -or $oldclient)) {
    Write-Host 'No Client found'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach :

```
"name1", "name2" | Get-Service | foreach-object {
    write-host $_.name $_.status
}
```

Of course depends on logic required after

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in a little more scalable solution, I would suggest following:

I used $appsRunning to increment each time the script find a running service, so if you are interested in a total count of running services (from the $services list) you could use that variable.

```
$services = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "NAME"; Description = "New App" },
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "NAME_old"; Description = "Old App" }
)
$appsRunning = 0

foreach ($service in $services) {
    $app = Get-Service $service.Name
    if ($app.status -eq "Running"){
        write-host $service.Description is $app.status
        $appsRunning++ 
    }
}

if ($appsRunning -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No app Running"
```